# Rails edit adding fields issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application that has an add page and and a edit page. You can add elements easily (there is no issues), but then when you go to edit those and click save, it adds the fields you added initially a second time.

Here is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @store do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product_form| %>
    <div class='field'>
      <%= product_form.text_field :name %>
      <%= product_form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= link_to "REMOVE PRODUCT", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add PRODUCT", :products %></p>
  <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => "primary small" %>
<% end %>
```

and my store.rb model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products, class_name: "StoreProduct"
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

my update action in my controller looks like:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @store.update(store_params)
      format.html { redirect_to store_products_path(@store), notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you see the product id field in the rendered html source while on edit page?

Comment: @ManojMonga, the html source for the form on the edit page has the product id inside the `action=""`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think it would be having the source_id in the action. And there should be hidden fields for id of each nested products.

Comment: We have a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `store_params` look like in your controller?  If `id` isn't one of the permitted values, then you can start to see the nested models created as new records each time the `update` action occurs.  You would want to have something like:

```
params.require(:store).permit(products_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#strong-parameters) on strong parameters for the `nested_form` gem.